# Does booting into windows causes start-up issues such as hibernation?

Tags: bootcamp, sleep-wake, power, power-management

I am using MacBook Air 2019 running OS X Catalina. For the past few weeks, I have been facing the issue with regard to my mac going to hibernate. This hasn't been the issue since I bought the mac this year. In fact, to be more precise, I think the mac hibernating issue started appearing when I downloaded windows Bootcamp on my system. I decided to do an SMC reset and everything went back to normal. I shut the lid of my laptop one night and woke up the next morning seeing my mac awake as soon as I opened the lid. In fact, this has not been happening since I did the SMC reset where I had to hold the power button each time to wake my laptop, which has been sleeping for a period of time. Now here's the thing. The following day, I decided to boot into windows to play some games and after I was done playing I booted back into Mac, closed the lid of my laptop and let it go to sleep. I wake up today, opening my laptop to see that the issue of hibernation is still there and I don't see my laptop waking up after opening the lid where in fact I had to press the power button to wake my mac up.

It seems pretty clear now that, my hibernation issue is linked to my Bootcamp installation and don't know how I can fix this. To be clearly honest, it isn't such a big deal to press the power button to wake but it is certainly frustrating at times.

I hope someone can help me out!